# Run NodeJs application with socket.io using Nginx as proxy server on AWS EC2

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx, socket.io, reverse-proxy

I am trying to run NodeJs application with socket.io using Nginx as proxy server on AWS EC2 and getting this error:
*Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MIsbMS_:1*
I am following this page directives https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-nodejs-websockets-socketio/

My nginx settings are as follows:

```
upstream socket_nodes {
    ip_hash;
     server 127.0.0.1:8080;
}
server {
    listen 80 ;
    listen [::]:80 ;
    root /home/ubuntu/NodejsProjects/Node3;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name mydomainname.com www.mydomainname.com;
    location / {
   proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://socket_nodes;
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
}
```

My index.js has following code

```
  var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);      
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen(8080);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
  io.sockets.on('connection',function (socket){

    socket.on('test', function () {
     console.log(data);
     socket.emit('testCl', 'Test successful!!');
    });
  });
```

In my index.html I have

```
 <p id='pp'></p>
    <button id="Btn1" onclick="cc();">Get test results</button><br/>


<script>
var socket = io();
var cc=function(){
socket.emit('test');
};
socket.on('testCl', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    $("#pp").text(data);
  });
</script>
```

After spending hours searching net I tried many things without success in html file such as

```
var socket = io();
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
var socket = io.connect('http://www.mydomainname.com:8080');
var socket = io.connect('http://myprivateIP:8080');
var socket = io.connect('http://mypublicIP:8080');
```

***Any help please***.

Answer (score 0):

Finally It is working.

All I have to do is create a new file in /etc/nginx/sites-available by copying nginx default configration file

```
sudo cp /etc/nginx/sites-available/default /etc/nginx/sites-available/mynewfile
```

Edit this file and put nginx proxy settings as given above in it and save.

link this mynewfile to sites-available directory

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/mynewfile /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
```

Now tested nginx files:

```
sudo nginx -t
```

Restarted nginx

```
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

Previously I was editing some existing file to work as reverse proxy for nodejs apps.